# Operations on nested arrays in APL

Tags: apl, dyalog

I have the data in the following structures:

```
Nums←56 66 19 37 44 20 18 23 68 70 82

A←(⍳¨(3≤⍳4)/⍳4)
┌→────┬───────┐
│1 2 3│1 2 3 4│
└~───→┴~─────→┘
```

What I want to do is create another nested array that would have elements with values from `Nums`, selected using indexes from `A`, looking like that:

```
┌→───────┬───────────┐
│56 66 19│56 66 19 37│
└~──────→┴~─────────→┘
```

Then I want to perform operations on every element of my array but I think I know how to go from there.
How do I create such array in APL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
(⊂Nums){⍺[⍵]}¨A
```

and you can then go ahead and appy youf fn:

```
(⊂Nums){fn ⍺[⍵]}¨A
```

Comment: Thanks. It does what I need but I'm now wondering whether there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do (which is: apply same operation on the selected segments of the vector, all segments having the same length).

Comment: In your example you have two segments with different lengths. How would you now control the length? 
One answer might be to apply the fn at segments of length 4:
(⊂Nums){fn 4↑⍺[⍵]}¨A
(nb: a 0 would be appended to the vector of length 3...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to structure the result

```
      A⌷¨¨⊂⊂Nums
56 66 19  56 66 19 37
```

Answer (score 0):

In NARS2000, easy:

```
  Nums←56 66 19 37 44 20 18 23 68 70 82
  A←(⍳3)(⍳4)     
  ⎕fmt A
┌2──────────────────┐
│┌3─────┐ ┌4───────┐│
││ 1 2 3│ │ 1 2 3 4││
│└~─────┘ └~───────┘2
└∊──────────────────┘
  ⎕fmt {Nums[⍵]}¨¨A
┌2─────────────────────────┐
│┌3────────┐ ┌4───────────┐│
││ 56 66 19│ │ 56 66 19 37││
│└~────────┘ └~───────────┘2
└∊─────────────────────────┘
```